# Splash: Unable to view web contents

Tags: lua, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I was trying to render HTML and view the website content using Splash. The script was working fine but suddenly I'm unable to view the website content using the same script for https://www.galaxus.ch/search?q=5010533606001 this website. The script is working fine for other websites but for this website https://www.galaxus.ch/search?q=5010533606001 I'm unable to view any content.

Note that, I've used Splash for the same website before and it worked fine that time.

```
function main(splash, args)
  splash:set_user_agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.63 Safari/537.36")
  splash.private_mode_enabled = false
  assert(splash:go(args.url))
  assert(splash:wait(5))
  
  splash:set_viewport_full()
  return {
    splash:png(),
    splash:html()
    }
end
```

[image]

Comment: I also experienced similar behaviour with one of my scrapers. Use [scrapy-playwright](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright) instead. It is an amazing library for scraping and quite fast IMO.

Comment: Yes that is what I am also thinking. I hope it will solve the problem. Is there any tutorial available on scrapy-playwright?

Comment: Go to the [docs](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright). The usage is quite straight forward